# When clicking a link on webview how to open it in another webview?

Tags: java, android, performance, webview, android-webview

I have two webviews the first is the browser, everytime I click or open a link on the first webview basically, it will load the link.
I want to open it in another webview, I mean everytime I click a link on the first webview, I want it to open on the second one how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `onLoadResource` and there fetch a new URL for a loading. Set this URL into your second WebView. But before that check, if your current page was finished loading.